# Struggling with partial initialization of nested C struct - expected '=' before '->' token

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm obviously missing something important here...

I have following definitions and would like to do a partial initialization of a nested struct, but
keep getting stated error.

I'd kindly ask for help, how to write this partial initialization in correct way...

```
struct cb_data {
    void (*filter_match)(struct bt_scan_device_info *device_info,
                 struct bt_scan_filter_match *filter_match,
                 bool connectable);

    ...

};

struct bt_scan_cb {
    const struct cb_data *cb_addr;
    sys_snode_t node;
};



static void scan_filter_match(
    struct bt_scan_device_info *device_info, struct bt_scan_filter_match *filter_match, bool connectable) {
  char addr[BT_ADDR_LE_STR_LEN];

  bt_addr_le_to_str(device_info->addr, addr, sizeof(addr));
}

static struct bt_scan_cb scan_cb = {
    .cb_addr->filter_match     = scan_filter_match,
  };
```

Thanks in advance for advice,
regards,
Bully.

Comment: You can't use the designated initialization syntax to initialize something that does not belong to the structure.

Comment: In C there is no "partial initialization". An object either is not initialized or is 100% totally recursively initialized (to `0` (of the right kind) in the absence of another initializing value). Maybe you want an uninitialized object and assign values to only part of it: `char a[3]; a[1] = '$'; /* UB to read a[0] or a[2] */` vs `char a[3] = { [1] = '$' }; /* a[0] == a[2] == 0 */`

Comment: You need to create an instance of `cb_data` and initialize it. Then you initialize `.cb_addr` with the address of your instance of `cb_data`.

Comment: You could change `const struct cb_data *cb_addr` to `const struct cb_data cb_addr` to nest the struct as a member instead of point to it. Then initialise as `static struct bt_scan_cb scan_cb = { .cb_addr = { .filter_match = scan_filter_match } };`

Comment: Hello, thanks for comments... I've learned a lot from them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing `scan_cb.cb_addr` before initializing it. This is undefined behaviour. There's no point in thinking of `scan_cb.cb_addr->filter_match` until `scan_cb.cb_addr` is initialized, so let's start with that.

```
static struct cb_data foo {
};

static struct bt_scan_cb scan_cb = {
    .cb_addr = &foo,
};
```

Now that `scan_cb.cb_addr` points to a valid structutre, it becomes trivial to initialize `scan_cb.cb_addr->filter_match`.

```
static struct cb_data foo {
    .filter_match = scan_filter_match,
};

static struct bt_scan_cb scan_cb = {
    .cb_addr = &foo,
};
```